# How to factory reset a bricked Oneplus 3T?

Tags: adb, fastboot, unbricking, oneplus

A friend gave me a bricked oneplus 3T and asked if I could do anything.

I assume bootloader is NOT unlocked and usb debugging NOT enabled.

I’ve tried msm download tool but I only was able to use the oneplus 3 one (instead of 3T). any time I try msm I get Sahara error after a few seconds. Looks like the phone changes state when I start uploading OOS.

I did manage to get to adb sideload and upload the OOS but the screen is still black after rebooting.

I’ve tried multiple usb ports 2.0 and 3.0 and different usb cables. I also tried other computers (always win 10).

If anyone would like to help I can provide more informations,
Anyway thanks for reading.

**Update : I’ve managed to use fastboot oem unlock and then ‘volume up’ two times then ‘power’ button to accept if anything is displayed on screen and I think it worked because now I can flash recovery and boot. I flashed twrp but when I boot in recovery I get a black screen. When I do adb shell I can use commands like twrp sideload**

Comment: It works better the other way round.  You provide all the pertinent information and then someone will try and help.

Comment: How did you manage to brick the device? Considering the age of the phone it could be a hardware problem like dead Flash memory or some other chip.

Comment: Sorry if I did not provided enough info, I’m new to android stack exchange. 
I’ve bricked the phone flashing the wrong os (op3 instead of op3T) since then I have a black screen and sometimes vibration. I randomly get access to adb or adb sideload or fastboot while playing with the power and volume keys. The point I don’t understand is why my phone is disconnected when I start the job in msmDownloadTool. I managed to skip the hwid check but then the phone disconnects and instantly reconnects and I get Sahara communication failed error or sometimes it’s stuck on firehose hand check failed.

Comment: @Robert yeah it could be but I don’t know how to make sure if it’s hardware or software issue. Would you have any idea of how I could make sure or even get a clue ?